# Как обратится к классу pdo, в функции Users shows();

Tags: классы, pdo, объекты

//Database.class.php

```
  class Database{
    public $isConn;
    protected $datab;

    // connect to db
    public function __construct($username = "root", $password = "", $host = "localhost", $dbname = "mcland", $options = []){
        $this->isConn = TRUE;
        try {
            $this->datab = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
            $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    // disconnect from db
    public function Disconnect(){
        $this->datab = NULL;
        $this->isConn = FALSE;
    }
    // get row
    public function getRow($query, $params = []){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    // get rows
    public function getRows($query, $params = []){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    // insert row
    public function insertRow($query, $params = []){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return TRUE;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    // update row
    public function updateRow($query, $params = []){
        $this->insertRow($query, $params);
    }
    // delete row
    public function deleteRow($query, $params = []){
        $this->insertRow($query, $params);
    }
}
```

//Users.class.php

```
class Users extends Database
{
    public function shows() {
        $getRows = $this->datab->getRows("SELECT * FROM users");
        die_r($getRows);
        $this->datab->Disconnect();
    }
}
```

P.S:
Выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

Comment: Намёк: `$this->datab` - объект PDO. Откуда у него меттод `getRows`?

Comment: public function getRows($query, $params = []){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: Так этот метод у какого класса: `PDO` или `Database`?

Comment: эм а выше class Database не видно что-ли?

Comment: Я вот не могу понять - откуда взялось у людей необузданное желание на каждый объект (!) создавать свой коннект? чем так плоха статическая переменная в этом конкретном случае?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, пока что так, в дальнейшем поменяю, спасибо за совет)))

Comment: @Ilshat, да просто не Вы первый так сделали, и в ответах на вопросы тут нередко предлагают делать такое. Вот уже даже просто интересно стало - может я что-то не так понимаю)

Comment: @АлександрБелинский меня больше интересует вопрос, зачем он с маниакальным упорством пишет try-catch-throw

Answer (score -1):

Вижу, что комментариями дело не обойдётся... Показываю очень упрощенный пример. Для того, чтобы вы могли его запустить и посмотреть, я изменил имя класса PDO на MyPDO, т.к. объявить его повторно не получиться.

```
<?php
// Где-то за кадром...
// Мы его не видим, а он есть ;)
class MyPDO {
    public function __construct(){
        // MyPDO constructor
    }
    public function prepare(){
        // Prepares a statement
    }
    public function query(){
        // Executes an SQL statement
    }    
}

// А это уже Ваш код
class Database {
    protected $datab;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->datab = new MyPDO();
    }
    public function getRows(){
        $this->datab->prepare();
    }
}
class Users extends Database {
    public function shows() {
         // Посмотрим, есть ли у объекта метод getRows
        print_r( get_class_methods($this->datab) );
    }
}
// Запускаем
(new Users)->shows();
```

Результатом примера будет следующее:

```
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => prepare
    [2] => query
)
```

Метода `getRows` мы не наблюдаем. Давайте на пальцах разберем почему. Мы создали экземпляр класса `MyPDO` и присвоили его свойству `datab`. Если очень примитивно, то класс живет в переменной и понятия не имеет, кто его использует. Он не знает ни о методах, ни о других свойствах, которые живут с ним по соседству. У него есть только свои методы и ими он может оперировать. Другое дело, когда его расширяют, т.е. как бы добавляют ему какие-то методы, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: ->prepare() идёт отсюда:                                            
 $this->datab = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); то есть самому pdo, а не классу

Comment: Превосходно. А как вы всё-таки объясните эту свою строку: `$getRows = $this->datab->getRows("SELECT * FROM users");`

Comment: говорю же он не работает, мне нужно к переменной $datab подключения, то есть $this->datab->method... не пашет, пробовал в index.php, $db = new Database(); $db->datab = $db; в итоге ошибка доступа, поменять protected $datab, и куча ошибок сталр

Comment: Если `$this->datab->method()`, то `method()` должен быть у `$this->datab`. Я могу только догадываться, что именно вам нужно. И т.к. я уже слегка устал, то буду просто ванговать: `$getRows = $this->getRows("SELECT * FROM users");`

Comment: И кстати, судя по всему, ваши классы в разных файлах. Надеюсь, что вы не забыли во втором подключить первый файл или использовать [регистратор](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: все норм) я юзаю spl_autoload_register

Comment: Проблема решена, сделал функцию: Register для бд:

Answer (score -2):

P.S:
Проблема решена, сделал функцию: Register для бд:

```
class Registry {
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($key, $val){
        $this->data[$key] = $val;
    }

    public function __get($key){
        if(isset($this->data[$key])){
            return $this->data[$key];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

$registry->datab = $db;
и потом вызвал $Users = new Users($registry); 
обработал в самой функции __construction: добавив $this->registry = $registry; и registry сделав private, теперь все работает

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/213884)

Comment: @Air, в очереди проверок необходимо проверять только те посты, про которые вы понимаете, о чем они. В противном случае следует их пропускать.